# Can't reference an MVT layer from Mapfile

Tags: gdal, mapbox, mapserver, vector-tiles, mapfile

I'm trying to add an MVT layer to my Mapfile, but it doesn't work and I ran out of ideas.
Some info about the layer I'm trying to add: https://support.regrid.com/articles/using-the-tileserver/

This is my LAYER definition in my Mapfile (based on the guidance of https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html and https://mapserver.org/input/vector/ogr.html)

```
LAYER
    NAME "Parcel"
    TYPE POLYGON
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    CONNECTION "MVT:https://tiles.regrid.com/api/v1/parcels/{z}"
    DATA "parcels"
    STATUS ON
END
```

By debugging the layer I get the following logs:

```
[Thu Dec 30 12:17:42 2021].906000 msOGRFileOpen(MVT:https://tiles.regrid.com/api/v1/parcels/{z})...
[Thu Dec 30 12:17:42 2021].906000 OGROPen(MVT:https://tiles.regrid.com/api/v1/parcels/{z})
[Thu Dec 30 12:17:43 2021].133000 msOGRFileOpen(): OGR error. Open failed for OGR connection in layer `Parcel'.
File not found or unsupported format. Check server logs.
[Thu Dec 30 12:17:43 2021].133000 msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'Parcel'.
[Thu Dec 30 12:17:43 2021].134000 freeLayer(): freeing layer at 01012900.
```

I'm expecting this to work because the following ogrinfo command runs without any issues:

```
ogrinfo "MVT:https://tiles.regrid.com/api/v1/parcels/14/3579/6522.mvt" parcels
```

I couldn't find a single example online about adding an MVT layer to a Mapfile.

Is there anyone who could prompt me in the right direction or just have a working example?

Comment: The idea behind vector tiles is to skip server side rendering like WMS and let the client software render the data with styles that can be customized. Naturally a WMS server can act as a vector tile client and convert data into WMS. However, it would be not a big surprise if MapServer did not support reading MVT even it does have a write support https://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-119.html.